# Is it bad practice to use reference assignment in PHP when handling potentially undefined variables?

Tags: php, reference, variable-assignment

I've been thinking of using reference assignment as a shortcut for dealing with potentially undefined variables.

In other words, instead of:

```
$foo = isset($this->blah['something']['else']) ? $this->blah['something']['else'] : null;
if (!is_null($foo) && ...){
    //do something with $foo
}
```

I could do this:

```
$foo = &$this->blah['something']['else'];
if (!is_null($foo) && ...){
    //do something with $foo
}
```

Seems simpler, right? Because of the way PHP handles assignment by reference, I don't have to worry about $this->blah['something']['else'] being defined, because if it doesn't exist it will be created automatically and set to NULL.

Is this strategy frowned upon?

Comment: I'd say it was bad practice. I would expect the second form to raise a notice regardless of the reference operator, and notices should be squashed wherever possible.

Comment: Right, except the second form won't raise a notice! PHP assignment-by-reference is tricky like that.

Comment: In the first part, why don't you considering using the `@` operator to deliberately suppress error notices?

Comment: Thanks @Matt, and yikes! That would then be another reason not to use it - it won't raise a notice even if it contains a mistake.

Comment: None of the answers will be accepted, Matt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to test if a variable is set and not null, then you better test:

```
if (! empty($this->blah['something']['else'])) {...}
```

This way you avoid creating two references to a value that could not even exist.

In my opinion, every time you create a new reference to the same value, your code becomes harder to understand at a glance.

If you need zero as non-empty, then you better create a global function like this:

```
function eempty(& $var) {
  return empty($var) && $var !== 0;
}
```

Comment: You make some good points but your first example is incorrect... calling empty() on an undeclared variable will throw a warning, I believe.

Comment: As stated in PHP documentation: "empty() is the opposite of (boolean) var, except that no warning is generated when the variable is not set". See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Answer (score 0):

I personally think it **could** be more conventional, but assigning a referred value like that seems a bit redundant to me. I'd just stick with the more commonly used ternary operator in your situation. Often it's a lot clearer to understand. Of course, you should follow your personal semantics as close as possible.